# Finding a count of all duplicates with a different last colum

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table of insurance policies and i am trying to find all of the policies that have the exact same information except in a different zip code (last column).

if anyone has any suggestions on how to find this it would be greatly appreciated

```
Policy    | Expiry   |  State|     Region  |  InsuredValue  |   Construction |  BusinessType| Zip

100242    | 2-Jan-21 |   NY |       East   |    1,617,630   |     Frame      |  Retail      | 10002
100242    | 2-Jan-21 |   NY |       East   |    1,617,630   |     Frame      |  Retail      | 10011
100242    | 2-Jan-21 |   NY |       East   |    1,617,630   |     Frame      |  Retail      | 10005
100242    | 2-Jan-21 |   NY |       East   |    1,617,630   |     Frame      |  Retail      | 10002
100242    | 2-Jan-21 |   NY |       East   |    1,617,630   |     Frame      |  Retail      | 10005
100242    | 2-Jan-21 |   NY |       East   |    1,617,630   |     Frame      |  Retail      | 10005
100242    | 2-Jan-21 |   NY |       East   |    1,617,630   |     Frame      |  Retail      | 10011
100242    | 2-Jan-21 |   NY |       East   |    1,617,630   |     Frame      |  Retail      | 10011
100242    | 2-Jan-21 |   NY |       East   |    1,617,630   |     Frame      |  Retail      | 10005
100242    | 2-Jan-21 |   NY |       East   |    1,617,630   |     Frame      |  Retail      | 10011
100242    | 2-Jan-21 |   NY |       East   |    1,617,630   |     Frame      |  Retail      | 10005
100242    | 2-Jan-21 |   NY |       East   |    1,617,630   |     Frame      |  Retail      | 10002
100242    | 2-Jan-21 |   NY |       East   |    1,617,630   |     Frame      |  Retail      | 10005
```

in this example I would want it to return:

```
Policy       Expiry     State    Region       InsuredValue    Construction    BusinessType   dupCount 

100242    | 2-Jan-21 |   NY |       East   |    1,617,630   |     Frame      |  Retail      | 3
```

dupCount is 3 because there are 3 distinct zipcodes for this data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use group by all columns (except Zip) and count by Zip.

```
SELECT policy,
       expiry,
       state,
       region,
       insuredvalue,
       construction,
       businesstype,
       COUNT(distinct zip) AS dupcount
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY policy,
             expiry,
             state,
             region,
             insuredvalue,
             construction,
             businesstype
    HAVING COUNT(distinct zip) > 1;
```

Comment: What if I wanted a total count of all of these rows instead of returning a count of how many dup zips?  A sum of all the dups

Comment: Just use subquery: select sum(t.dupcount) from (<full query above>) t

Comment: i tried that before but I got an error with nested aggregate Functions. I must have messed up on the syntax because yours worked, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below.

```
select t.Policy, t.Expiry, t.State, t.Region, t.InsuredValue, t.Construction, t.BusinessType, count(1) 
from (
  select distinct Policy, 
  Expiry, State, Region, 
  InsuredValue, Construction, 
  BusinessType, Zip from tablename) t
group by t.Policy, t.Expiry, t.State, t.Region, t.InsuredValue, t.Construction, t.BusinessType;
```